# Getting a string from a referenced table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am relativly new to the SQL language. I can do a basic select, but for performance increase, I'd love to know if it is possible to merge the two queries I am doing at the moment into one.

**Scenario**: There are two tables. Table one has a few columns, one of them is a VARCHAR(45) named 'user', and another one is a INT which is called 'gid'. In the second table, there is a primary key column called 'gid' (INT) and a column called 'permissions' which is a TEXT column and it contains values seperated by ';'.

I have a user name, and want the text in the permissions column. The current way I do it is by fetching the gid of the first table, then doing a second query with the gid to get the permissions.

I've heard there are other ways to do this, and I have searched on Google, but I'm not sure what I should do.

EDIT:

Like this:

[image]

Comment: sounds like you want a UNION. It would help if you shared the queries

Comment: Table structure and the query you're using would be helpful

Comment: I've added a table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t2.permissions
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
 where t1.user = '<SPECIFIED NAME>'
   and t1.gid = t2.gid;
```

or you could use `INNER JOIN` syntax:

```
select t2.permissions 
  from table1 t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.gid = t2.gid 
where t1.user = '<SPECIFIED VALUE>'
```

Comment: horrible -- use modern joins don't teach a new user this 30 year old crap

Comment: instead of complaining, you could have given an alternative: `select t2.permissions from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.gid = t2.gid where t1.user = '<SPECIFIED VALUE>'`
And the 30 years old crap performs very well by the way.

Comment: I did give an alternative.

Comment: Then there was no reason to complain. Let the one asking decide what he likes best

Comment: Sorry, that isn't how stackoverflow works, I invite you to read the FAQ.  This isn't a message board.

Comment: Added the `INNER JOIN` example from the above comment to the answer body.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you use a JOIN.  A join connects two tables in a select statement.

Like this

```
select *
from usertable u
join permissiontable p on u.gid = p.gid
```

This will give you all the columns from both tables with the id column joined.  You can treat the joined table just like any table (eg select a sub-set of columns in the select list, add a where clause, etc).

You can read more about joins in any intro sql book or doing a google search.

Comment: Why select 4 million columns if only one column is needed? Do your systems suffer from too much unused network bandwidth?

Comment: @Ronald - Did you miss the part of my answer where I said *select a sub-set of columns*?

Comment: change `uid` by `gid`